# Hide table row when clicked on button in that row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with on each row there is a column with a delete button with id="hiderow".

What I want is to hide that specific row when the button on that row is clicked. I have this code for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hiderow").click(function(){$(this).parents("tr").hide(); })
});
```

The crazy thing is that it only works for the first row. If I do it for the second or other rows it does not work. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Assign an id for tr and get the id of the clicked button and then hide the row with this id

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `class` instead of `id` to listen event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hiderow").click(function(){$(this).parents("tr").hide(); })
});

<td class="hiderow">your content</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

`$("#hiderow")` - this one is selector by `ID`, and id should be unique for all elments at page. So `$("#hiderow")` return only first element with that id.

If you have multiple elements and want to aply some logic to each of them you should use class or at least `$("#table>body>tr")` selector to get all of them.